# Is there an alternative to "dag_dir_list_interval" in Airflow to upload dags from storage to scheduler?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, cd

hope you are all doing well.

I am using an airflow instance deployed on Kubernetes using Helm Chart.
I setup my dag folder inside a rook nfs storage.
I need these dags to be processed instantly by the airflow scheduler.
Airflow provide an environment variable, namely "dag_dir_list_interval". In my configuration I set this variable to 1 which means that the scheduler will check every seconds if there is a new dag file inside the dag folder.

It works but as you can imagine it is very not efficiency as it costs a lot in terms of CPU Usage.

I wanted to know if there were any alternative to this environment variable, for example, let's say a call API that allows me to tell to the scheduler "hey there is a new dag to be processed" without checking every seconds for new file inside the nfs storage.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess restarting the webserver is the only way.